# Table between two hr tags in a div. Table doesn't take all attributes from div

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

Brand new to HTML/CSS and experimenting.

I'm trying to place a table between two hr tag lines (one on top, one on bottom). I want to have the width of the table match the width of the lines, center everything horizontally on the page, and have sticky positioning.

What's happening is, the lines follow the width I set, are centered, and have the positioning I want. The table has the positioning, but not the width and is left-aligned with the lines (not with the page or anything).

```html
<div style="width:100%; max-width: 800px; margin:auto; position:sticky; top:0px; ">
  <hr>
  <table style="border:1px solid black; background-color:Coral">
    <tr>
      <th><u>Section 1</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 2</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 3</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 4</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 5</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 6</u></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
      <td><a href="S1WordFormatting.html">Word<br/>Formatting</a></td>
      <td><a href="S2Lists.html">Lists</a></td>
      <td><a href="S3Tables.html">Tables</a></td>
      <td><a href="S4ImagesandVideos.html">Images and<br/>Videos</a></td>
      <td><a href="S5Linking.html">Linking</a></td>
      <td><a href="S6InputTypes.html">Input Types<br/>(Text Boxes)</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Why would the table take the positioning from the div, but not the width or margin? Also, why would it left-align with the lines?

I know I can fix this by adding the width and margin to the table tag, but can it be fixed in the div tag? Or am I misunderstanding/missing something about how div tags work? I thought it would apply any styling to any elements between the tags.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: why use the `<hr>` tag at the end and beginning of an element in the first place. Thats what you have border-top and bottom for. `<hr>` is use to split 2 elements apart like between 2 paragraphs. Not to mark the top or bottom of an element.

Comment: the `margin` is the space outside of an element. the inner space is called `padding`. As such, the table cant be influence by the div's margin as the table is inside the div not outside. The table has a smaller width then the div. The div will take 100% of the document space unless limited. The table will take up to 100% of the div's  space unless an overflow happens. If the content of the table is smaller, then of course it will not consume the entire space avaiable but only the space needed.

Comment: Besides of that there is nothing wrong, you shouldnt use a table for styling purpose. For layouting like you do, you have flexboxes and css-grid.

Comment: It's mostly for testing purposes. Trying to understand how all of these things work as I go along the learning process and what changing parameters does. I'm literally only a few days into learning HTML/CSS lol.

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
<div style="width:100%; max-width: 800px; margin:auto; position:sticky; top:0px; ">
```

do :

```
<div style="flex-direction: column;width:100%;display: flex;max-width: 800px;margin:auto;position:sticky;top:0px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

A table will not consume 100% of the parents width by default. the width of the table will depend on the `content` by default. So just add `width: 100%;` to the table style and it will consume 100% of the parents width.

```html
<div style="width:100%; max-width: 800px; margin:auto; position:sticky; top:0px; ">
  <hr>
  <table style="width: 100%; border:1px solid black; background-color:Coral">
    <tr>
      <th><u>Section 1</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 2</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 3</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 4</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 5</u></th>
      <th><u>Section 6</u></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
      <td><a href="S1WordFormatting.html">Word<br/>Formatting</a></td>
      <td><a href="S2Lists.html">Lists</a></td>
      <td><a href="S3Tables.html">Tables</a></td>
      <td><a href="S4ImagesandVideos.html">Images and<br/>Videos</a></td>
      <td><a href="S5Linking.html">Linking</a></td>
      <td><a href="S6InputTypes.html">Input Types<br/>(Text Boxes)</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

inline styles (set using `style=` are one-off definitions.

> An inline CSS is used to apply a unique style to a single HTML element
> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

if you want to reuse the same style multiple times, use css classes

```
<style>
.commonWidthAndMargin {
width:100%;
max-width: 800px;
margin:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="commonWidthAndMargin" style="position:sticky; top:0px; "> 
    <hr>
      <table class="commonWidthAndMargin" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:Coral">
        ...etc
      </table>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Also, it's the default behavior of tables to not expand to their parent. A child div would take up 100% of its parent by default. see: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926939/what-is-the-default-width-of-an-html-table-cell-td)

Comment: There is no difference between inline styles or css-styles or head styles with exeption of the specifity weight. Besides of that, that is not the question here. You miss the question completely and not trying to anwser the question itself. As such your anwser does not fit as an anwser just as a comment.

Comment: There is a difference in how they're inherited. Tables will not inherit width from an inline style of its parent.

Comment: neither will a table inherit the space in a css-file. The content of the table is smaller. By default a table will only consume as much space as needed.

Comment: in this scenario it makes more sense to use a class that causes the table to adjust shared values with its parent

Comment: maybe but this still doesnt solve the actual issue. css-style or inline style have no influence to the tables default width. What every you say it missies the actual problem and question.

Comment: which you eddited in after critized you. Still not anwsering the question. An anwser must be a definete solution and that you still havent provided.

Comment: seems like a matter of opinion on what problem is being solved